# How to force user to re-enter the input if it doesn't meet requirement with for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Here's my code to require user to enter the number of characters of password they want to generate. If they enter number < 8, i want to force them to re-enter. Other wise, password will be generated. But i got stuck with the for loop since it produced indefinite print.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import string
import random

lower_string = string.ascii_lowercase
upper_string = string.ascii_uppercase
special_string = "!@#$%&*()[]{}"
number = '0123456789'

list_string = [lower_string, upper_string, special_string, number]

password = ''

password_length = int(input("Enter length of password: "))


while password_length < 8:
    print("Hey, this password's length is not good. Enter > 8")
    continue
else:
    for _ in range(password_length):
        x = random.choice(random.choice(list_string)) 
        password = password + x
print(password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place the `input` statement inside the while loop

```py
while True:
    password_length = int(input("Enter length of password: "))
    if password_length < 8:
        print("Hey, this password's length is not good. Enter > 8")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thanks henry. I edited my code and it worked perfectly now.